# Pivot For Pivot Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table

i have a query for pivot table and i get these result :

> ItemNo | Shift | Mon | Tue | Wed |
>   ItemA | 1 | 10 | 20 | 30
>   ItemA | 2 | 40 | 50 | 60
>   ItemA | 3 | 70 | 80 | 90
>   ItemB | 1 | 100 | 110 | 120
>   ItemB | 2 | 130 | 140 | 150
>   ItemB | 3 | 160 | 170 | 180

and then i want to add shift field at the day like 'Day.Shift'

Expected :

> Mon.1 | Mon.2 | Mon.3 | Tue.1 | Tue.2 | Tue.3 | Wed.1 | Wed.2 | Wed.3 |
>   10 | 40 | 70 | 20 | 50 | 80 | 30 | 60 | 90 |
>   100| 130 | 160 | 110 | 140 | 170 | 120 | 150 | 180 |

Image :
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Read this: http://modern-sql.com/use-case/pivot

Comment: @Jackques : In your answer if you have Mon.1 | Mon.2 | Mon.3 | Tue.1 | Tue.2 | Tue.3 etc. Is this for ItemA or ItemA or both?

Comment: @JonWay : for Both item Jon.

Answer (score 2):

You should do `UNPIVOT` and then do `PIVOT`:

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE
(
    ItemNo VARCHAR(32),
    [Shift] INT,
    Mon     INT,
    Tue     INT,
    Wed     INT
)

INSERT @Test
VALUES
('ItemA', 1, 10, 20, 30),
('ItemA', 2, 40, 50, 60),
('ItemA', 3, 70, 80, 90),
('ItemB', 1, 100, 110, 120),
('ItemB', 2, 130, 140, 150),
('ItemB', 3, 160, 170, 180)

SELECT ItemNo, [Mon.1],[Mon.2],[Mon.3],[Tue.1],[Tue.2],[Tue.3],[Wed.1],[Wed.2],[Wed.3]
FROM (
    SELECT ItemNo, Item + '.' + CAST([Shift] AS VARCHAR) AS Item, DayShift
    FROM (
        SELECT ItemNo, [Shift], Mon, Tue, Wed
        FROM @Test
    ) p
    UNPIVOT (
    DayShift FOR Item IN (Mon, Tue, Wed)
    ) u
) s
PIVOT (
MAX(DayShift)
FOR Item IN ([Mon.1],[Mon.2],[Mon.3],[Tue.1],[Tue.2],[Tue.3],[Wed.1],[Wed.2],[Wed.3])
) p
```